# How to create a WMS Service to display a geo-reference image

Tags: open-source-gis, wms

I currently have little experience in the opensource area and I'm guessing this is where I need to go if I want to create a WMS Service without needing ArcGIS Server.  Basically my goal is to take a local geo-referenced image (geo-jpeg) and create a WMS service to display that image.  I've done some searching on this topic and I can't seem to find any specific information on this.  I would prefer not needing to create a MapServer installation but if that's one of my best options, I will try going that route.  So at this point I was hoping for some direction on how to create a WMS service, hopefully without needing to setup my own server.  Maybe a blog post or tutorial on doing this.  Thanks...

Answer (score 8):

For a non-programming (but not FOSS) way you could create a free account and try to upload your image to [GIScloud](http://www.giscloud.com/). WMS is one of the outputs you can get fron your project there. Check [docs](http://www.giscloud.com/docs/) for more information.

For more ambitious way - [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) might be good way. I find it easier to interact with than MapServer. Check OpenGeo tutorials for a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for the tip with GISCloud.  So I went ahead and tried this, enble the WMS feature for the map I created but I can't see to get any GIS clients to connect to the WMS address given.  All I get is failed to connect when I paste the WMS address given.  Is there something more I need to do or add to the address?

Comment: @wilbev: Where did you paste the link exactly? If you want to have a quick preview you can display your WMS layer in QGIS - just hit the button 'Add WMS layer' and fill parameters. If you want to display it in a browser you can generate a code for Google Maps overview with GISCloud. Or build a simple viewer with, [OpenLayers](http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/) or [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms).

Comment: I have tried in QGIS.  I paste the exact URL from the WMS tab in GIS Cloud in the URL field.  The error message I get back is"Could not understand the respone.  The wms provider said: Download of capabilities failed: Error downloading...gives the WMS address and says server replied: Internal Server Error.  Maybe something is wrong on GIS Cloud's side with this?  Also, I tried to the Google Maps too, and it will takes me to the correct location but it's not displaying the raster layer for some reason.

Comment: @wilbev: Strange. Perhaps try Map > Share and Publish > Embed. choose either option that is convenient for you and hit 'Popup preview'.

Comment: radek:  That's what I did to attempt to use the Google Maps.  When I click on the Popup preview, it only shows the Google map basemap, where the image is located but no raster image is shown.  I have no idea why the WMS url doesn't work.  Are you able to get them to work with no problems?  I even tried a second account and I get the same result.  Unless I'm doing something wrong, which I'm not doing much other than copying a url, I can't see this working for anyone.

Comment: Just tried it with some random public map and it did worked for me. Is your projection set up properly? Is your image georeferenced in correct way? Try including google map as a base layer in your project perhaps? Then you can see if it displays in correct position in the world.

Comment: I also tried about 10 different public maps and most had google maps for the baselayer.  Of those I tried, I only got one to visually show up in the popup preview.  Kind of seems GISCloud is very sensitive to the data in the may and possibly a projection problem as you suggest.  My image is definitely projected and georeferenced.  It shows up perfect with any baselayer in the GISCloud map.  It is in a UTM projection, so not web Mercator.  So when you say it worked fine for you, are you talking about the WMS url?  It looks like it's the same URL for all maps within a given account.

Comment: @wilbev: Perhaps it's worth dropping a line to help center - might be a problem on their side then. They always replied to me within few days and were very helpful. It's still pretty new service I think, co might be rough on the edges..

Answer (score 4):

I have a [tutorial](http://www.ianturton.com/tutorials/bluemarble.html) that describes how I set up GeoServer for this using the Blue Marble dataset. It should take you about an hour assuming you are reasonably happy with installing software on your system.